# Writing a brief report in a job

Tags: punctuation

I recall a comma limit rule with respect to many things (inanimate) in a list e.g. "I have completed an initial patrol of all the interior/exterior points, including: doors, openings, passages, stairways, courtyard, entry gates & surroundings; also, garbage/recycle room & elevaor area @ P1:

How can I make this most readable?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're intending to ask, "how can I make this most readable."

I'd suggest the following for something that is more than 4 items long for the sake of readability:

> I have completed an initial patrol of all the interior/exterior points, including:
>
> - doors
> - openings
> - passages
> - stairways
> - courtyard
> - entry gates & surroundings [NB logical grouping]
> - garbage/recycle room
> - elevator area @ P1